# Creating File instance within code

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have the following short code snippet which I try to do unit testing on it via mockito

```
public String getExecutable()
{
    String result = executable;
    String ex = !hasExtension() ? executable + ".bat" : executable;
    File f = new File( dir, ex );
    if ( f.isFile() )
    {
        result = ex;
    }

    return result;
}
```

The `dir` is an instance of the class `File` which is been given via constructor to the class so no problem. Only this line:

```
File f = new File( dir, ex );
if ( f.isFile() ) {
..
}
```

So does exist any chance to mock out this via Mockito to make some tests on it so i can control the result of `isFile()`? Any idea?

Comment: Ugly but you could create said file (as a directory if you want it to go wrong)

Comment: I know it's ugly and of course i could create a directory with those files etc. But this is the vaporized version. I need to check several extension like .exe,.com,.bat,.cmd,.vb etc. That's reason i wan't a way via Mockito. Apart from that: Do you have a better solution for those lines?

Comment: Roughly what I was searching: http://misko.hevery.com/2008/07/08/how-to-think-about-the-new-operator/ - avoid `new` if you want to be able to test. Like in Kenster's solution you get a better separation for free if you think twice about `new`

Comment: That's exactly the result i'm taking from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `dir` is a member variable for the class containing `getExecutable()`? You could abstract `dir` into something that may contain files:

```
class FileContainer {
    private final File dir;
    public FileContainer(File aDir) { dir = aDir; }
    public boolean contains(String aFile) {
        return new File(dir, aFile).isFile();
    }
}
```

Have your class hold one of these `FileContainer` objects, and use its `contains()` function to test for files. Arrange to inject a mock version of the `FileContainer` for testing. The mock version would override `contains()` and return whatever you want.

Comment: Your assumption about dir class is correct. Better separation of concerns. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One idea is to extract `new File( dir, ex )` to a new protected method and overwrite it during the test to return a mock.

```
public class YourClass
{
    // ...

    public String getExecutable()
    {
        String result = executable;
        String ex = !hasExtension() ? executable + ".bat" : executable;
        File f = createFile( dir, ex );
        if ( f.isFile() )
        {
            result = ex;
        }

        return result;
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    protected File createFile( String ex, String dir )
    {
        return new File( dir, ex );
    }
}
```

Before executing the test:

```
@Test
public void shouldReturnExecutableFile()
{
    YourClass subject = new YourClass()
    {
        @Override
        protected File createFile( String ex, String dir )
        {
            // return a mock for File
        }
    };
}
```

It is one of the techniques presented in Working Effectively with Legacy Code by Michael Feathers.

Comment: I have accepted the answer of Kenster, cause it is better separation of concerns. Thanks.